# Retrieve only specific SMS from SMS database

Tags: android

I have 20 numbers of contacts stored in array and I would like to retrieve only those contact's sms and then process them accordingily?

Is this possible? I mean can I write where clause to store the contacts in the query and then retrieve if so how to go about doing it?

or should I use for loop to retrieve the SMS one my by one?

Inside the loop something like this:

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, "from=+14015963069", null,null);
```

It would be great if somebody could guide me to this?

Thanks!

**Update:**

Tried the below as per suggestions:

```
Uri uriSMSuri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");
int argcount = 2; // number of IN arguments
        String[] args = new String[]{ "+14103599690", "+167890" };
        StringBuilder inList = new StringBuilder(argcount*2); //for adding the ?
        for(int i=0;i<argcount;i++)
        { 
            if (i > 0) 
            { 
                inList.append(","); 
            }
            inList.append("?"); 
        }

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSuri, new String[] {"*"}, "address IN ("+inList.toString()+")", args, null);
```

but I am still getting the following log error:

```
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662): Process: com.ylg.smsapp, PID: 32662
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ylg.smsapp/com.ylg.smsapp.Sms}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: field (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM threads WHERE field IN (?,?) ORDER BY  date DESC
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: field (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM threads WHERE field IN (?,?) ORDER BY  date DESC
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:181)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:422)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at com.ylg.smsapp.Sms.onCreate(Sms.java:112)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
05-04 07:35:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(32662):    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using "IN"

```
String[] args = new String[]{ "+1234576", "+167890" }; 

cursor = contentResolver.query(uriSMSURI, PROJECTION, "address IN (?)", args, null);
```

Comment: I get no such column for field IN - Please log here: http://pastebin.com/Jm1cPZYs

Comment: 'field' is the column name in your database. you can try changing it to "address" ?   the available fields are  [_id, thread_id, address, person, date, protocol,
read, status, type, reply_path_present, subject, body, service_center, locked]

Comment: Hmm. I am still getting the same error. Please check my question update. Let me know I have done it right?

Comment: would something like that help ? Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI , null, "address IN ( ?)", new String[] { "+1234576", "+167890"}, null);

Comment: If I use the above I get "Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range. The statement has 1 paramenters.

Comment: It's a typo. should have two '?'.   IN(?,?)

Comment: Hey! This is good for only 2 numbers what if I require for 20 numbers?

Comment: do a for loop to append the required number of  "?".

Answer (score 1):

use OR conditions in where clause of database query.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?